# Network profiling in VS2019 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Has the network profiler been removed?

In previous versions you could select the network profiler but in 2019 I cannot find it.  I want to be able to view the network requests my code is making:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that feature was removed, since I also couldn't find it anywhere in VS 2019 anymore.

Also, judging from [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/):

> With Visual Studio’s new Network tool, developers can now easily record information about all HTTP network operations made through the **WinRT HttpClient** API including HTTP request and response headers, request and response payloads, cookies and detailed timing information amongst other things. **Operations made using the old .NET HttpClient API aren’t captured.**

which might be a deal breaker for a lot of people anyway.

With that in mind, you can use a 3rd party tool, like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which is a more professional tool IMHO than Fiddler, since it doesn't need to act as a proxy in order to capture network traffic (like Fiddler does), it rather [captures packets directly from a network adapter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChWorksCapturePackets.html) itself.

It can do a lot more than just capture the HTTP traffic and a lot of security experts use it for network packets analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find it either. But if it helps and you need to see the traffic and the calls for debugging purposes you could use Fiddler

Fiddler was a free and pretty advanced tool used to profile the network calls from your computer, I used fiddler before Network profile tool was available in VS 2015.

So now that is gone I am back  using fiddler and I don't need VS Network traffic tool anymore